# Possible to avoid repetitive try catch in this scenario?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, try-catch

Sometimes data is deleted from a database by a user which has been referred to. A try catch in razor will handle this just fine, but is there another way?

Current Situation: The model holds a list of Boxes. Each Box has a Container. Safeguarding against Container deletion to avoid errors means using try catch.

No error handling,

```
<td>@m.Container.Name</td>
```

Error handling,

```
<td>@try{@m.Container.Name}catch { Deleted }</td>
```

Many lists have similar situations, where it is possible that relational data may be removed. Is there a better way to accomplish this aside from this try catch approach?

Some extra code to help with the example:

View Model:

```
public class BoxVM
{
 List<Box> Boxes { get; set; }
}
```

Models:

```
public class Box
{
 public int BoxId { get; set; }
 public Material Material { get; set; }
 public Container Container { get; set; }
}

public class Material
{
 //fk
 public int BoxId { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Container
{
 //fk
 public int BoxId { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult showBoxList()
{
 var vm = new BoxVM();
 vm.boxes = _boxRepo.Get().ToList();
 var materials = _materialRepo.Get().ToList();
 var containers = _containerRepo.Get().ToList();
 foreach(var box in vm.boxes)
 {
  box.Material = materials.Where(m => m.BoxId == box.BoxId).Single();
  box.Container = containers.Where(c => c.BoxId == box.BoxId).Single();
 }
 return View(vm);
}
```

View:

```
@model BoxVM

foreach(var m in Model.boxes)
{
 <p>@m.Container.Name</p> @*// Breaks if specific container was deleted *@
 <p>@try{@m.Container.Name}catch{<text>Deleted</text>}</p> @*// Doesn't break, but is there a better way? *@
}
```

Comment: Can we see the action? If the deletion happens there, you already know what's deleted.

Comment: @veblock - I posted a slightly more verbose example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a better way to accomplish this aside from this try catch approach?

Yes. Use an approach which supports a verbose referential integrity policy allowing for the deletion of a single node in an object graph while maintaining the relevance of the object graph.

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't know what your display requirements are, but the simple way to go about it is:

```
foreach(var m in Model.boxes)
{
    if (null != m.Container)
    {
        <p>@m.Container.Name</p>
    }
}
```

plus else part if you need to display something. You can also do that inline.

More on that:

If there's no matching container here:

```
box.Container = containers.Where(c => c.BoxId == box.BoxId).Single();
```

you should get an exception because of `Single()`. What's the content of `box.Container` when you step out of that line?

Comment: Calling .Container will throw an objectcontext exception.

Comment: Was asking if you go with Code First, or have a db handcrafted first.

Comment: `'((new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<project.Models.ProjectModels.Box>(vm.Boxes)).Items[56]).Container' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'` which is caught internally by EF and does not interrupt the runtime environment.

Comment: I see. If you go with `.SingleOfDefault()` in the action, are you able to check `if (null != m.Container)` in your view without objectcontext exception?

Comment: I actually had it set to .SingleOrDefault but found no difference. So no, I am not able to check in the view if that is used without getting the exception. Part of the problem is that at one point, the Container for that Box was valid, but then the Container entry in the database was deleted in the Container table.